# .NET 8 Core "unresolved symbol" when running with docker-compose

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package-restore

In my .NET 8 Core API app, when I run `dotnet run`, everything is working. But Im using a docker-compose, and there come the problems.

When I run my app with `docker-compose up --build`, my IDE stops to resolve the NuGet packages installed in all the projects of my solution. And, important point : it builds well, I never meet build issues.

So let's say I have imported 2 packages :

```
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

before building with docker-compose, no issue at all.
After building, I would have this issue : `Cannot resolve symbol 'EntityFrameworkCore'`.
And so on for all NuGet packages.

I've tried lots of things to try to fix the issue :

- Invalidate IDE cache
- change from Rider to VS
- Clone solution in another computer

But it has never fixed the issue. When I do `dotnet resolve`, it works, but only temporarily: after a new rebuilt, the error appears again.

---

**SOLUTION**

After many hours I finally find out a solution. In docker-compose.yml, add those lines the web config:

```
volumes:
    - /app/obj/
    - /app/bin/
    - /app/out/
```

Then add those lines in the `.dockerignore` file :

```
bin/
obj/
out/
```

Comment: I suppose you have the correct version in the packagereference?
If the version is incorrect it falls back to a local version. In production or C/D environments this could lead to an error.
Do you use anything of trimming or optimizations in release mode?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @IsmailHassani For testing, I've tried to let only 1 package :
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.2" />
But it doesnt change anything to the problem...
And there is no kind Trimming/Optimization in the project.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

After many hours I finally find out a solution. In docker-compose.yml, add those lines the web config:

```
volumes:
    - /app/obj/
    - /app/bin/
    - /app/out/
```

Then add those lines in the `.dockerignore` file :

```
bin/
obj/
out/
```